# Jersey 2.x and Tomcat8 returning NullPointerException, HTTP status 500

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8

I'm trying to make a simple rest service for an android app but I can't seem to get it to work. Im getting either 404 (if I use servlet 2.5 and glassfish.servletcontainer) or Nullpointer with http status 500 and this error message if i use servlet 3.0. I cant figure the problem out.

I think I'm mixing jersey 1 and 2 up but I have no idea where.

Error looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.binaryNameToPath(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2495)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findLoadedClass0(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2711)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1184)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndPoint</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndPoint</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Jax RS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey 2.23.2 -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

..and the simple java class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/EndPoint")
public class EndPoint extends Application{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getMsg() {
       return Response.status(200).entity("hai!").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yahoo, another problem that could be solved by not using an application container, tomcat, to create a web server and `web.xml` to define routing... Why do people stick to this aged and outdated technology?

Comment: Why? Shits, get taught in school. That's why. What do you suggest I should use instead?

Comment: My subjective choice for Java would be `vert.x`. The benefits are: it is not an app container, but a library so fully debuggable via a normal application run or tests and not suffering the issues you have above; it is trivial to write web servers with; it has brilliant documentation and tutorials in one place; it is very cleanly written and it has a much higher throughput than tomcat. And no, it is not a project I am participating in :) For Java8 use version 3, for Java 7 version 2.

Comment: Okay! Thank you, I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your EndPoint class to:

```
@Path("/endpoint")
public class EndPoint{

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response getMsg() {
   return Response.status(200).entity("hai!").build();
}
}
```

Lets suppose `EndPoint` class is in `com.test` package so you need to change web.xml configuration to:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>     
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Attention to `<param-value>com.test</param-value>` in web.xml. It is determine where Jersey should search for your Rest classes.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: I'm glad it was useful :)